# Firebase + JS: Error: set failed: value argument contains undefined in property

Tags: javascript, node.js, json, firebase

As part of a larger program that inserts data into a Firebase Real-Time Database based on dates, I have the following function that given a date updates the data for that day.

```
/** Updates database for a single day
     * @param {string} day - A date string in the format 'YYYY-MM-DD'
     * @param {ApiManager} apiManager - An instance of ApiManager to fetch data
    */
    async updateSingle(day, apiManager) {
        idList.forEach(async id => {
            let reference = ref(this.db, `${day}/${id}`);
            let data = await apiManager.getDataApi(day, id, apiManager.season);
            console.log(data); // undefined
            set(reference, data);
        });
    }
```

Whenever this function runs it gives the below error, which I can't figure out. I wrote the program a couple of months ago and it worked fine. When I returned to it some days ago, to continue my work, this was what met me.

```
file:///c:/Users/xyz/node_modules/@firebase/database/dist/node-esm/index.node.esm.js:10636
        throw new Error(errorPrefix + 'contains undefined ' + validationPathToErrorString(path));
              ^

Error: set failed: value argument contains undefined in property '2023-02-23.848'
    at validateFirebaseData (file:///c:/Users/xyz/node_modules/@firebase/database/dist/node-esm/index.node.esm.js:10636:15)
    at validateFirebaseDataArg (file:///c:/Users/xyz/node_modules/@firebase/database/dist/node-esm/index.node.esm.js:10628:5)
    at set (file:///c:/Users/xyz/node_modules/@firebase/database/dist/node-esm/index.node.esm.js:12794:5)
    at file:///c:/Users/xyz/src/firebase_manager.js:30:13
    at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:96:5)
```

Running the `getDataApi()` returns a JSON response, which is a list of soccer match JSON objects that looks like below. I am able to get this data when running `getDataApi()` on its own.

```
[
  {
    fixture: {
      id: 971801,
      referee: 'Istvan Kovacs, Romania',
      timezone: 'UTC',
      date: '2023-02-21T20:00:00+00:00',
      timestamp: 1677009600,
      periods: [Object],
      venue: [Object],
      status: [Object]
    },
    league: {
      id: 2,
      name: 'UEFA Champions League',
      country: 'World',
      logo: 'https://media-3.api-sports.io/football/leagues/2.png',
      flag: null,
      season: 2022,
      round: 'Round of 16'
    },
    teams: { home: [Object], away: [Object] },
    goals: { home: 2, away: 5 },
    score: {
      halftime: [Object],
      fulltime: [Object],
      extratime: [Object],
      penalty: [Object]
    }
  },
  {
    fixture: {
      id: 971803,
      referee: 'Artur Soares Dias, Portugal',
      timezone: 'UTC',
      date: '2023-02-21T20:00:00+00:00',
      timestamp: 1677009600,
      periods: [Object],
      venue: [Object],
      status: [Object]
    },
    league: {
      id: 2,
      name: 'UEFA Champions League',
      country: 'World',
      logo: 'https://media-3.api-sports.io/football/leagues/2.png',
      flag: null,
      season: 2022,
      round: 'Round of 16'
    },
    teams: { home: [Object], away: [Object] },
    goals: { home: 0, away: 2 },
    score: {
      halftime: [Object],
      fulltime: [Object],
      extratime: [Object],
      penalty: [Object]
    }
  }
]
```

Answer (score 0):

so JSON standard does not allow `undefined` as a value, which is why firebase throws an error when validating the JSON.

You *did* console.log your object, but it does not recursively show all nested objects.

To find the bad property, do:

`console.log(JSON.stringify(data))`

There you’ll see where is that `'2023-02-23.848'` property that has `undefined` as value, and then you can assign some value to that key for this to work.

Comment: The `'2023-02-23.848'` property (I think) refers to the location the data should be placed. The `.` separates the date from the league ID, but I don't know where it gets this notation from as I place it in the Firebase with `/`-notation. When doing `console.log(JSON.stringify(data))` it still just print `undefined` to the console.